# How to tokenize an array and matrix in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, token, tokenize

I am building a Java parser that will do some mathematical operations with matrices (multiplication, addition, subtraction). My program already does those operations with numbers. But I am stuck with tokenizing and parsing arrays and also matrices, as a result.

In the code, I have an interface with the following methods:

```
public interface ExpressionNode
{

  /**
   *
   * Each class derived from ExpressionNode representing a specific
   * role in the expression should return the type according to that
   * role.
   * 
   * @return type of the node
   */
  public int getType();

  /**
   * Calculates and returns the value of the sub-expression represented by
   * the node.
   * 
   * @return value of expression
   */
  public double getValue();

  /**
   * Method needed for the visitor design pattern
   * 
   * @param visitor
   *          the visitor
   */
  public void accept(ExpressionNodeVisitor visitor);

}
```

And each of the {Variable, Constant, Addition, Exponentiation, Function, Multiplication, Sequence (base class for Addition and Multiplication)} is implementing the ExpressionNode interface.

My question is: How and where can I add an ExpressionNode for the array or should I create a separate interface that will handle it?

Comment: Since `ExpressionNode` has `double getValue()` you'll probably need another interface that represents a matrix or vector (matrix with one column/row). Thus it might also be wise to rename `ExpressionNode` to `ScalarExpressionNode` or introduce that as a subinterface.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your reply. But it is still unclear how can I tokenize the array itself. Could you please give me an idea of how to do that? For example, for a scalar, I use the following code:     tokenizer.add("(?:\\d+\\.?|\\.\\d)\\d*(?:[Ee][-+]?\\d+)?", Token.NUMBER);. How can I do that with an array?

Comment: Please don't put loads of code into comments - [edit] your question instead.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what `tokenizer` is or what your input would look like, so it's hard to tell.